# How do I redirect after rendering, without an error in express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to redirect from "/loading" to "/done" after the data has loaded (here after the timeout), but it throws this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\parot\Documents\Learning\Websites\starting\node-website-starter-files-master\node-website-starter-files-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (C:\Users\parot\Documents\Learning\Websites\starting\node-website-starter-files-master\node-website-starter-files-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:888:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\parot\Documents\Learning\Websites\starting\node-website-starter-files-master\node-website-starter-files-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:926:18)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\parot\Documents\Learning\Websites\starting\node-website-starter-files-master\node-website-starter-files-master\server.js:42:25)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port: " + server.address().port)
})

app.get("/loading", (req, res) => {
    res.render("prefab", { input: "Loading..." })
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.redirect("/done")
    }, 30000)
})

app.get("/done", (req, res) => {
    res.render("prefab", { input: "Done!" })
})
```

This is the "prefab.ejs" file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%=input%>
</body>
</html>
```

It may be a stupid question but please go easy on me, I'm new to coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have res.render and res.redirect both together, that's the error,

you will need to redirect from prefab route and after whatever time you want.

You might want to use jquery or any other front end library to redirect from prefab itself.

Comment: How does redirecting from the prefab route work?